# Kubernetes deployment helm running first command in shell then run outside the shell

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to run some commands in my K8 deployment yaml.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - export ABC=hijkl
      - command 2
```

Basically, I need to run the export command in the shell. After which, it should continue to run command 2 outside the shell. I can't seem to get the syntax right (eg. am I missing `&&`, or double quotes etc). Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bourne shell `sh -c` option takes only a single command word, so anything you want to run in that shell needs to be in a single YAML list item.

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - export ABC=hijkl; command 2
```

You'll frequently see YAML [block scalars](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#81-block-scalar-styles) used in a context like this, so you can have embedded newlines and it will look more like a normal shell script.

If you're just setting an environment variable to a fixed string, you can also do that at the Kubernetes layer and skip the intermediate shell:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: ABC
          value: hijkl
      command:
        - command
        - '2' # (note, YAML single quotes so this is read as a string)
```

Comment: For the first option, command 2 will also run in the shell correct? Since you mentioned that it needs to be a single YAML list item. So in my question, I want to run command 2 outside the shell, so that's why I should put as the next list item am I right? So why is my syntax in my question wrong?

Comment: A container only runs one process; also, environment variables can only be set for a process and its children.  You can't run a shell and then a second process outside the shell, without having an outer shell to coordinate them.  One possibility is to use the shell `exec` built-in, `export ... && exec command 2`, which will replace the shell with the command and leave the command as process 1.

Comment: You could also use this pattern with an entrypoint wrapper script in your Docker image; do the setup work and then `exec "$@"` to run the actual main process.  Just be aware that you need to use Kubernetes `args:` and not `command:` to override the image's `CMD`, leaving its `ENTRYPOINT` intact.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the export command within ` or '

Below is a reference :

```
spec:
  containers:
    - command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - export 'ABC=hijkl'
      - command 2
```

Comment: I tried this. But the pod will just go into a `completed` state before crashing repeatedly. I suspect this is because the export command just ends there and it does not continue to run command 2? Describe pod and pod logs do not reveal the reason for the crash

Comment: use export -p also in the command and refer this [doc](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export).